# WMI GetObject Error

Tags: vbscript, wmi, wmi-query

On Windows XP, in my vbscript, I am using

GetObject("winmgmts:\.\root\cimv2")

to get WMI service object, but always get error: (null): Invalid syntax. I checked the syntax, it should be ok. I even tried to rebuild the Repo as suggested  [here](http://katyscode.wordpress.com/2007/02/03/tutorial-how-to-fix-wmi-corruption) , but still got the same error. I guess it might be permission/security policy issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb684728) is wrong you are missing a `\`

instead use

```
GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2");
```

or even better you can get the instance of the WMI class directly including the WMI path

```
GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk='C:'")
```